# How do I nest requests so they share the same auth config in Paw?

Tags: paw-app

Just trying out Paw for the first time … I think this is a basic question but trying to understand how to use the various concepts:

- Documents
- Groups
- Requests
- Environments
- Sessions

For this example, let's say I am wanting to work with the Sonos API, so I create a new **document** (⌘N) and I name it "Sonos".

Next, I create my first **request** which returns my [households](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/households/). When I created this request, I had to configure OAuth 2.0 auth. So far, so good.

For my second request, I want to return the [groups](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/groups/getGroups/) in a household. How do I set this second request (and subsequent requests) so that it inherits the auth config created in the first request? **Groups** seems to be arbitrarily folders, **environments** seems to be more for specifying dev/prod etc and I am unclear what **sessions** are (but wondering if that's what I want).

This is a long way of asking "how do I nest requests so they share the same auth config"?